# Android Kotlin Unable to convert 3 channel GrayScale image to 1 channel for tensorflow lite image input

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am facing problem converting 3 channel RGB to  grayscale and step down to 1 channel grayscale needed by tensorflow lite model image input , below are my code snippets

Model input
[{'name': 'serving_default_input_1:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([ 1, 64, 64,  1]),.......}]

```
  bitmap =toGrayScale(bitmap)
    val tfliteModel = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(this, "model.tflite")
        val tfliteOptions = Interpreter.Options()
        //tfliteOptions.setNumThreads(4);

        val interpreter = Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions)

        val imageTensorIndex = 0

        val imageShape: IntArray =
            interpreter.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape() // {1, 64,64, 1}
  val imageDataType: DataType = interpreter.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType()

var inputImageBuffer = TensorImage(imageDataType);
 val imgprocessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
           // .add(ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(64, 64))
            .add(ResizeOp(64, 64, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
            .add(NormalizeOp(127.5f, 127.5f))
            .add(QuantizeOp(128.0f, 1 / 128.0f))
           
            .build()
        inputImageBuffer.load(bitmap)  // Insufficient buffer overflow 

     inputImageBuffer = imgprocessor.process(inputImageBuffer)


 fun toGrayscale(srcImage: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        val bmpGrayscale =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImage.width, srcImage.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bmpGrayscale)
        val paint = Paint()
        val cm = ColorMatrix()
        cm.setSaturation(0F)
        paint.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm)
        canvas.drawBitmap(srcImage, 0f, 0f, paint)
        return bmpGrayscale
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

well just solve , need to add  .add(TransformToGrayscaleOp()) to imgprocessor

```
val imgprocessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
           // .add(ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(64, 64))
            .add(ResizeOp(64, 64, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
            .add(NormalizeOp(127.5f, 127.5f))
            .add(QuantizeOp(128.0f, 1 / 128.0f))
            .add(TransformToGrayscaleOp())  <<<-----
           
            .build()
```

Comment: Really happy to see that someone is using it. https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/blob/master/tensorflow_lite_support/java/src/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/image/ops/TransformToGrayscaleOp.java :)

Comment: TransformToGrayscaleOp() just got  not enough of expose in main google tutorial as many old model still on 1 channel Gray, On different  note , why codelab lite model maker only support .jpg as image input not extend to PNG

Comment: Drop a comment for .png issue on TensorFlow forum and tag Yugi Li for that.